# Binding a tagged template literal to an outer object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to access a value that exists on the object where a tagged template literal is located, without introducing extra syntax.

```
function myTemplate(str: TemplateStringsArray) {
  console.log(this.myValue)
  return str[0] 
}

function Create(options) {
  return options
}

const value = Create({
  myValue: 'something',
  template: myTemplate`
    some text
  `
})
```

I would like the `console.log(this.myValue)` to print the value located on the object it's nested within.

The following works, but I don't want to have to bind the template like this.

```
const value = Create({
  myValue: 'something',
  template: myTemplate.bind(this)`
    some text
  `
})
```

I tried binding it in the `Create` function like so:

```
function Create(options) {
  options.template.bind(options)
  return options
}
```

But of course, it doesn't work as the tag has already been evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I had to return a function from the template literal and pass in the options from the create function

```
function myTemplate(str: TemplateStringsArray) {
  return function(options: any) {
    console.log(options.myValue)
    return str[0] 
  }
}

function Create(options: any) {
  options.template = options.template(options)
  return options
}

const value = Create({
  myValue: 'something',
  template: myTemplate`
    some text
  `
})
```